# Interpretability of MLPClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have a question regarding the interpretability of machine learning algorithms.

I have a dataset looking like this: 
[tabular data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXrPx.png)

I have trained a classification model (MLPClassifier from Scikit-Learn) and want to know which features have the biggest impact (the highest weight) on the decision.

My final goal is to find different solutions (combination of features) which will have a high probability (>90%) to be classified as 1.

Does somebody know a way to get these solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the feature importance during a classification task the classification methodology has to be randomforest or decision tree, both implemented in sklearn,

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=2,random_state=0)
clf.fit(X, y)
#After the fit step
clf.feature_importances_
```

The feature importance will tell you how much weight each feature has, if your MLP classifier is trained properly, it will assign nearly similar importance to various features in your network,